# Need to pass condition in SQL function

Tags: sql, function, stored-procedures, parameters

I wrote this function to remove blank spaces from a zip code:

```
Create FUNCTION fn_zip (@zip VARCHAR(30))
    RETURNS VARCHAR(30)
AS
BEGIN

    SET @zip = REPLACE(@zip,' ','')

    IF @zip IS NULL OR @zip = '' OR PATINDEX('%[^0-9A-Za-z-]%',@zip) > 0 OR PATINDEX('%[^-]%',@zip) = 0
        SET @zip = '99999'

    RETURN @zip
END
```

Unfortunately it only removes spaces for USA zipcodes. Other countries still show spaces. What I can do? 
my output is country **canada zipcode 114 akz** but I want country **canada zipcode 114akz.**
This function has four stored procedure also.

Comment: You realize of course that spaces are legitimate characters for mailing code is some countries.  Canada is one example.

Comment: Then it seems like this is an application problem rather than an sql problem. But we can pretend that all avenues for fixing the application have already been explored.

Comment: Also: can you give some examples of inputs that produce unwanted outputs: what you got vs what you expected?

Comment: Can you post examples of conditions you want to pass, zip code values that would be passed with the conditions, and what you expect the function to return based on those values? **Edit them into your original question.** Don't put that info here into comments, because many comments are hidden by default and people won't see them.

Comment: I am thinking to pass where condition -
where !='USA'